# Rails: Remote true on simple_form for update action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, simple-form

I'm attempting to set a simple form to do remote_true to execute a javascript file on the update action. Here's what it looks like:

the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body,
              label: "Product Body",
              input_html: {
                rows: 12,
                id: "update_product_body" 
              }  
  %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-warning", value: 'Update Product', id: "update_product_submit_button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The update action:

```
  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The goal is to simply execute the following javascript on the successful completion of the update action to change the submit button:

app/views/products/update.js.erb

```
function update_response() {
  alert("Javascript executed.");
  var submit_button = $("#update_product_submit_button");
  submit_button.text("Product Successfully Updated Locally")
};
update_response()
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in ProductsController#update
ActionController::UnknownFormat
Extracted source (around line #47):
45
46
47
48
49
50

    if @product.update(product_paras)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If the Rails ujs component is taken out of play by something like a syntax error in your JS files the request is sent as a normal form submission (with the html format). Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: On the error page it just says ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)```

Comment: I can also confirm that my app has rails ujs